# Strange window opens randomly and closes very quickly

Tags: malware, windows

It has been some time now that in Windows 11, I experience this weird issue:

Now and then, I see a window (something bigger than a command prompt) opening and closing immediately.

It has a blue color, and I am unable to see if there is text inside. For sure if there is it is just a few characters.

It always opens at the same place; the center of the left monitor (I have 2 monitors).

I have tried to:

- disable all the Microsoft Office tasks
- not open Opera (as I thought it could have been related...)
- check all the registries and startup options (I don't find anything strange)

But it is still here.

As for the frequency, sometimes 2 or 3 times a day, sometimes not even once... I don't have an exact timing for it.

I am thinking to reinstall the OS as I don't know what this thing is doing.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: What does this have to do with `content-security-policy`?

Comment: Blue screen typically means the Powershell window.

Comment: Have you tried all these suggestions: https://www.google.com/search?q=blue+window+pops+up+then+disappears

Comment: the tag was a mistake while i was looking for security i am notsure it is a powershell, if i open a powershell it is not blue also..i know it used to be blue but i don't have it blue i have tried some of those suggestions but they are not really solutions..noone got his problem solved!

Comment: I would use [autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns) and see what is running in the background.

Comment: You need to describe, then, what you've tried else we'll repeat the same things.